# SignalR cómo obtener el código del usuario en la clase Hub

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

Tengo una aplicación que se autentica a través del active directory. Primero obtengo el usuario, nombres y apellidos del dominio de la siguiente forma:

```
        string usuario = string.Empty;
        string nombres = string.Empty;
        string apellidos=string.Empty;

        UserPrincipal user = GetActiveDirectoryUser(HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Replace("BNP\\", ""));
        usuario = user.SamAccountName;
        nombres = user.GivenName;
        if (user.Surname == null) { apellidos = string.Empty; } else { apellidos = user.Surname; }

    private UserPrincipal GetActiveDirectoryUser(string userName)
    {
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"BNP"))
        using (var user = new UserPrincipal(ctx) { SamAccountName = userName })
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user))
        {
            return searcher.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;
        }
    }
```

Y luego comparo con mi base de datos si ese usuario tiene acceso o no al sistema. Si tiene acceso, guardo su codigo de usuario (el de la base de datos) en una cookie:

```
Response.Cookies["CodUsuario"].Value = codUsuario;
```

Ahora, esta es mi clase Hub, por el momento tengo un método que obtiene el contenido de una tabla de la base de datos.

```
    [HubMethodName("obtenerUsuariosEnLinea")]
    public void ObtenerUsuariosEnLinea()
    {
        DataTable usuariosEnLinea = new DataTable();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "select us.Usuario,us.Nombres+' '+us.Apellidos AS Nombres from dbo.SesionUsuario sesion INNER JOIN dbo.Usuario us ON (sesion.CodUsuario=us.CodUsuario) ORDER BY Nombres";
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    usuariosEnLinea.Load(reader);
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(usuariosEnLinea);
    }
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            ChatHub nHub = new ChatHub();
            nHub.ObtenerUsuariosEnLinea();
        }
    }
```

Esto funciona correctamente, el problema es que a ese query yo quisiera ponerle una condicional "WHERE" pasando el código de usuario almacenado en la Cookie. De esta forma:

```
string codUsuario= Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request.Cookies["CodUsuario"].Value.ToString();
string query = "select us.Usuario,us.Nombres+' '+us.Apellidos AS Nombres from dbo.SesionUsuario sesion INNER JOIN dbo.Usuario us ON (sesion.CodUsuario=us.CodUsuario) WHERE sesion.CodUsuario='"+ codUsuario + "' ORDER BY Nombres";
```

Este query se ejecuta correctamente al iniciar la aplicación, pero cuando realizo algún cambio en la base de datos y ese método se ejecuta de nuevo, me bota este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He googleado bastante y he probado varias soluciones como por ejemplo crear un diccionario de datos y sobreescribir el evento OnConnected para asociar el connectionID con el código de usuario de la base de datos, pero para poder buscar el código de usuario en ese diccionario de datos necesito obtener el connectionID y para obtenerlo debo utilizar Context.ConnectionId , y el Context sigue siendo null cuando se llama por segunda vez.

Espero me puedan ayudar amigos, no sé que más intentar.

Gracias !

Comment: HOla no sé si ya has solucionado el error. Pero estoy viendo que estás intentando usar el context antes de asignarlo. El context parece que se asigna en la línea donde accedes al GlobalHost

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, aún no lo soluciono, me podrías brindar un ejemplo sobre cómo asignar el context para poder utilizarlo?

Comment: En tu código me da la sensación de que lo estás cogiendo en esta línea         IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();

Comment: Oh, ya entendí, pero el "context" que declaro con esa linea solo tiene estas opciones: "Clients", "Equals", "GetHashCode","GetType","Groups" y "ToString". Pero para acceder a la cookie, necesito la propiedad "Request". El Context que tiene esta propiedad y que sale null pertece a la clase "HubCallerContext HubBase"

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

El problema, por lo que comentas, es que cuando se modifica algo en la base de datos y salta el evento OnChange del SqlDependency, realmente no hay ninguna petición HTTP, por lo tanto, Context es siempre nulo. Es decir, aunque el cambio en base de datos se realice por un usuario mediante una petición Http, el evento se lanza en un hilo de ejecución diferente, por lo que no hay ninguna referencia a la petición original.

Si he entendido bien el propósito de tu código, quieres que cuando un usuario inicie sesión, se informe al resto mediante SignalR de la nueva lista de usuarios conectados. Esto lo haces haciendo un SqlDependency sobre la tabla de usuarios conectados. ¿Por qué no pruebas a mover esta lógica al punto en el que el usuario inicia sesión y se modifica la tabla? Es decir, cuando se inicia sesión y se actualiza la base de datos, llama al método `ObtenerUsuariosEnLinea` para que se notifique al resto. Pero habría que eliminar la parte de la SqlDependency para evitar que se produzca la misma excepción.

Échale una pensada y me comentas qué tal te fue.